# Multiple button on a single form but only one submit button?

Tags: php, forms

I want to pass data from a single form, but it has another 2 button to add and delete questions, the problem is when I click on any of problem or create a question problem, the form problem to the action url.. I just want when I click on the Submit button then action is activated.

```
<form method='POST' action='scripts/generateguide.php'>
    <button class='deleteCon'>Delete</button></p>
    <button class='addP'>create quesiotn</button>
    <input  name='createGuide' type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

The default `type` of a `button` element is `submit`.

You can specify `type="button"`.

It is better practise, however, to give it a name and a value so that you can perform whatever task you want it to do server side should the JS fail, and then call `event.preventDefault()` in the event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution instead of using

```
<form method='POST' action='scripts/generateguide.php'>
    <button class='deleteCon'>Delete</button></p>
    <button class='addP'>create quesiotn</button>
    <input  name='createGuide' type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

I have to use this

```
<form method='POST' action='scripts/generateguide.php'>
     <input  name='create question' class='addP' type="button" value="Submit">
     <input  name='delete' type="submit" value="btton" class='deleteCon'>
    <input  name='createGuide' type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```